# FrameLayout and Bitmap Leaking Memory causes OOM

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am leaking memory on FrameLayout and Bitmap from  this fragment below. Is is wise to have weak references on framelayout? I'd like to know how to perform it. The holder.image should I use weak references as well? I am using Universal-Image-Loader for loading large images.

```
One instance of "android.widget.FrameLayout" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 1,786,072 (13.27%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "byte[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
android.widget.FrameLayout
byte[]
```

---

```
43 instances of "android.graphics.Bitmap", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 1,897,648 (14.10%) bytes. 

Biggest instances:
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x40e73900 - 1,048,656 (7.79%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x40e79280 - 281,960 (2.09%) bytes. 


Keywords
android.graphics.Bitmap
```

---

**Fragment**

```
   @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //final View view;
    context = getActivity();
    holder hold = new holder();

    View  view = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);

    //int imageWidth = loadedImage.getWidth();
    //int imageHeight = loadedImage.getHeight();


    if (convertView == null) {
        //view = (LinearLayout) inflaterr.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
        hold.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);


    } else {
        view = (View) convertView;
        hold.image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);



        imageLoader.displayImage(values.get(position).get("imagePath").toString(),
        hold.image, options, animateFirstListener );

    }
```

---

```
class holder
        {
            ImageView image;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always inflating a new `FrameLayout`, even if you're not using it (when `convertView != null`). Only inflate it when `convertView` is null.

Also, there is a good resource on [managing bitmap memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) on the android developer site.

Edit:

Taken from the [readme at Android-Universal-Image-Loader project](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader):

> If you often got OutOfMemoryError in your app using Universal Image 
>   Loader then try next (all of them or several):
>
> - Reduce thread pool size in configuration (.threadPoolSize(...)). 1 -    5 is recommended.
> - Use .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) in display options. Bitmaps    in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.
> - Use .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache()) in configuration or disable    caching in memory at all in display options (don't call
>     .cacheInMemory()).
> - Use .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT) in display options.    Or try .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).
> - Avoid using RoundedBitmapDisplayer. It creates new Bitmap object with    ARGB_8888 config for displaying during work.

Comment: Thanks!! saves my memory alot for Framelayout!!! I am using Universal-Image-Loader for my images, basing from the link you've given, what can I do with my images with UIl? thanks

Comment: I have that config sir, all of them. How about weak references on ImageView with UIL?